# Django: AJAX ManyToManyField in admin

Tags: ajax, django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I want to display `ManyToManyField`s in admin just like `filter_horizontal` does, but populate the options as the user types into the filter field. There are many options and loading them all at once takes a lot of time.

I found [django-ajax-filtered-fields](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/) but it seems to me an overkill as it requires changes to model classes, when all I want to do is to replace every multiple select field in a form.

Writing a custom widget field that inherits from `admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple` seems to be the right way. So I am trying to roll my own widget:

```
class MultiSelectWidget(FilteredSelectMultiple):
    class Media:
        # here should be some js to load options dynamically
        js = (
            "some_js_to_load_ajax_options.js",
        )

    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        # this initializes the multiple select without any options
        choices = [c for c in self.choices if str(c[0]) in selected_choices]
        self.choices = choices
        return super(MultiSelectWidget, 
                     self).render_options([], selected_choices)

class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['m2m_field'].widget = MultiSelectWidget('m2m_field', is_stacked=False)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminForm
```

which renders correctly.

But I am not sure how to implement this `some_js_to_load_ajax_options.js` ajax part. Should I write my own jQuery snippet or modify `SelectFilter2` which comes with `admin/media/js`? Anybody been there before?

**edit:**
Although not related to the core of the question, as I only want to override the field's widget, the shorter way is to use `formfield_overrides`:

```
class MultiSelectWidget(FilteredSelectMultiple):
    # as above

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': MultiSelectWidget},
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I started from your code and I used a custom javascript to retrieve values from photologue Photo model; please note that I'm using grappelli and the Django url that get the json object is hardcoded; also the field in my model is called "photos":

```
# urls.py
url(r'^get_json_photos/(?P<query>[\w-]+)/$', 'catalogo.views.get_json_photos', name='get_json_photos'),


# views.py    
from photologue.models import Photo
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def get_json_photos(request, query):
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)[:20]
    p = [ {"name":photo.title, "id":photo.id} for photo in photos ]
    response = json.dumps(p)
    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")


# admin.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class MyFilteredSelectMultiple(FilteredSelectMultiple):

    class Media:
        js = (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/core.js",
              settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/SelectBox.js",
              settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + "js/SelectFilter2.js",
              settings.MEDIA_URL + "js/ajax_photo_list.js")


class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def clean(self, value):
        return [val for val in value]


class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photos = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Photo.objects.none(), required=False,
        widget=MyFilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name="photos", is_stacked=False))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GalleryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            i = kwargs["instance"]
            gallery = Gallery.objects.get(pk=i.pk)
            qs = gallery.photos.all()
        except:
            qs = Photo.objects.none()
        self.fields['photos'].queryset = qs

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        widgets = {
            'photos': MyFilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name="photos", is_stacked=False)
        }


class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date_added', 'photo_count', 'is_public')
    list_filter = ['date_added', 'is_public']
    date_hierarchy = 'date_added'
    prepopulated_fields = {'title_slug': ('title',)}
    filter_horizontal = ()
    form = GalleryForm


# ajax_photo_list.js 
(function($){
$("#id_photos_input").live("keyup", function(){
    var querystring = $("#id_photos_input").val();
    if (querystring) {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/get_json_photos/"+querystring+"/",
            cache: false,
            success: function(json) {
                if (json) {
                    var list_from = $("#id_photos_from option").map(function() {
                        return parseInt($(this).val());
                    });
                    var list_to = $("#id_photos_to option").map(function() {
                        return parseInt($(this).val());
                    });
                    for (var pid in json) {
                        if ($.inArray(json[pid].id, list_from) == -1 && $.inArray(json[pid].id, list_to) == -1) {
                            $("#id_photos_from").prepend("<option value='"+json[pid].id+"'>"+json[pid].name+"</option>");
                        }
                    }
                    SelectBox.init('id_photos_from');
                    SelectBox.init('id_photos_to');
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
}(django.jQuery));
```

I'm thinking to make it generic, since is not the first time that I have this problem,

Comment: +1 for these two lines that I added to my ajax backed selectbox `code`SelectBox.init('id_photos_from');                   SelectBox.init('id_photos_to');`code`

Comment: your many to many relation is gallery-photo? In the gallery view/template, you have a field "photo" with multiselect? Is this in models.py: class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm): ?

Answer (score 0):

I would hack the select filter, it has a nice set of functions that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If the UI of [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) appeals to you, you could use [Django-Select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io) in the Admin.

For m2m it might work like you suggested:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': ModelSelect2MultipleWidget},
    }

    # required to make jquery available to select2
    # has to be loaded via Admin class (and not via widget or form class) for correct order in output
    class Media:
        js = ("ext/js/jquery.min.js",)
```

Ajax works by adding the following URL pattern to `urls.py`:

```
# if using ModelWidget
url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
```

Of course, you can also provide your own view implementations, see the documentation linked above.

I'm currently not using it for m2m but for reverse foreign key relations, so I'm using it in a custom form in the Django admin, instantiating the widget explicitly. Thus, in case it's not working with `formfield_overrides`, the long way would be an option.