# textbox for foreignkey field in django

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

So I have a form where user can post "Parent" details also form for Kid for a different model.

what i need is :

1. In Kid_form I'd like to allow the user to type the "family field" instead of dropdown list
2. allow users to add a Parent object in case it doesn't exist. (if it's possible to be auto-complete field would be great)

   3. allow all users to link child to any other user's Parent object

**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_family(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST)
        kid_form = KidForm(request.POST)
        if parent_form.is_valid() and kid_form.is_valid():
            parent = parent_form.save(commit=False)
            parent.save()
            kid = kid_form.save(commit=False)
            kid.family = parent
            kid.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        parent_form = ParentForm()
        kid_form = KidForm()
        template = 'add_family.html'
        context = {'parent_form': parent_form, 'kid_form': kid_form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

**template**:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ parent_form.title }}
    {{ parent_form.address }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ kid_form.family }}
    {{ kid_form.title }}
    {{ kid_form.age }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Select2](https://select2.github.io) and [django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This is an input widget with (optional) multiple selection and autocomplete. For creating new entries on the fly, have a look at `django_select2.forms.Select2TagWidget` and its subclasses.

You have to add the django-select2 URLs to your app to make autocomplete work, and also call the django-select2 plugin on the select fields as explained in the documentation.

Setup the field in your `forms.py` like this for m2m relations:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    m2m_field = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    widget=ModelSelect2MultipleWidget(model=RelatedModel, search_fields=['some_name__istartswith']),
    queryset=RelatedModel.objects.all(), required=False)
```

or for ForeignKey relations like yours:

```
class KidForm(Form):
    family = ChoiceField(
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(model=Parent, search_fields=['title__istartswith']),
    queryset=Parent.objects.all(), required=False)
```

in `urls.py`:

```
# use any url pattern to your liking
url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
```

In my JS code I'm initializing the plugin explicitly (didn't work for me the other way):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'django_select2/django_select2.js' %}"></script>
$('select#id_family').djangoSelect2();
```

For integrating into the admin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610206/621690.

Comment: it is a great package. I just didn't know how to use it the easy way!..